# Force iMacro to Pull Info From Text File or Excel?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, imacros

Here's my current script:

```
VERSION BUILD=8810214 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://www.clientsite.com/register.php
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:signup-form ATTR=ID:new-email CONTENT=testemail@gmail.com
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:signup-form ATTR=ID:new-username CONTENT=testuser
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:signup-form ATTR=ID:signup-form-passwd CONTENT=password123
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:signup-form ATTR=ID:passwd1 CONTENT=password123
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ID:signup-form ATTR=ID:looking_for_work
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:signup-form ATTR=ID:submit_btn
URL GOTO=http://www.clientsite.com/logout.php
```

On lines 4 and 5 you'll see where a username and email is entered.  I need to pull this information from a text file or excel file.  I can add it all in one file or make two files, whichever is easier.

I just don't understand how to reference those files and make my script go from one username to the next and one email to the next...

Answer (score 0):

```
VERSION BUILD=8810214 RECORDER=FX
SET !DATASOURCE data.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 4
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
VERSION BUILD=8810214 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
URL GOTO=http://www.clientsite.com/register.php
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:signup-form ATTR=ID:new-email CONTENT={{!COL0}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ID:signup-form ATTR=ID:new-username CONTENT={{!COL1}}
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:signup-form ATTR=ID:signup-form-passwd CONTENT={{!COL2}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=ID:signup-form ATTR=ID:passwd1 CONTENT={{!COL3}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:RADIO FORM=ID:signup-form ATTR=ID:looking_for_work
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=ID:signup-form ATTR=ID:submit_btn
URL GOTO=http://www.clientsite.com/logout.php
```

Try it like this.

data.csv should look like this.

```
email, new username,password, password1
```